# How to implement Nested JsonObject /JsonArrey in One Json Value?

Tags: android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I have a Json Format 
Json Url

http://inter.youdao.com/intersearch?tag=simple-eh&from=en&to=hi&q=spin

I need only first i

first i - n. घुमाव; चक्रण; झुकाव

second i. v. घूमना; कातना

Is it possible that first i + second i word only first  word =  n. घुमाव, v. घूमना

The problem was showing result in android no eh velue.
How to get hindi word.

### Json Result

```
{
"data": {
"eh": {
"": "spɪn",
"ukphone": "spɪn",
"ukspeech": "spin&type=1",
"trs": [
{
"i": "n. घुमाव; चक्रण; झुकाव"
},
{
"i": "v. घूमना; कातना"
}
],
```

### Android Implement :

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                             try {
                                // Parsing json object response
                                // response will be a json object
                            JSONObject result = response.getJSONObject("data");
                                String eh= result.getString("eh");
                                JSONObject result1 = response.getJSONObject("eh");
                                String hindi= result1.getString("trs");
                                jsonResponse = "";
                                jsonResponse += "Hindi: " + hindi ;
                                txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);
} catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hide the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: yes json parse is available but jsonobject have 2 other object value how to get that value.

Comment: that is not a JSONObject, that is JSONArray.

Comment: can you plz fix my problem i am new in android how to implement that JSONarray

Comment: it doesn't work this way. Either you want to learn and spend time on that (reading the question marked as a duplicate at least) or you don't want to learn, and pay somebody to do your work instead of you. `plz fix my problem` looks like you don't want to learn.

Comment: I am trying to get that value more then week but I am still failed.

Comment: I am trying show many way but not working ...Android receive json value but not convert to json

Comment: you probably should find some lesson about parsing JSON, or more specific - JSONArray.

Comment: When you run your current code, what gets printed?

Comment: txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse); null but Toast No value for hindi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally fix the Problem

Thanks
here is code :

```
try {
                        // Parsing json object response
                        // response will be a json object
                        String syncresponse = response.getString("data");
                        JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(syncresponse);
                        String synckey = object2.getString("eh");
                        JSONObject object3 = new JSONObject(synckey);
                        JSONArray jArray1 = object3.getJSONArray("trs");

                        for(int i = 0; i < jArray1 .length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject object4 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                            String comp_id = object4.getString("i");
                            String replace = object4.getString( "i" ).replace( ";", "," );

                            translate.setText(mWord + "=" + comp_id);
                        }
```